# Android load urls after loading custom html in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I working on android application , I am loading custom html data with a submit button and form submission .. custom html loads successfully in webview later when I redirect from inside the html content it asks for external browser . How can i fix to be work in same webview ?

here is my code:

```
 wb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webv);

        wb.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
String customHtml= "<html>...</html>"

wb.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line 
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: can you provide any working example for this scenario.

Comment: @user6768912 Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code;

```
WebView view = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

((LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_about)).addView(view);

view.loadData(getString(R.string.about), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

in your string.xml

```
<string name="about"><![CDATA[ <html> <head></head> <body style="text-align:justify;color:#059bba;background-color:#FF‌​F;"> here enter your text </body> </html> ]]> </string>
```

Comment: no read my question again .. my custom html is loading successfully , after that when i press submit button and submit the form on url it asks for external browser